# indexing in array in for loop [wrong output] [batch]

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to loop through an  array by step size of 2. what i want is to take 2 values in one iteration and then process it (i.e say i and i+1 index needs to processed in everyloop). for that i wrote following snippet.

```
for /l %%a  in (1,2,!counter!) do (
    set username=!array[%%a]!
    set /a nextindex=%%a+1
    echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[%nextindex%]!]
)
```

when i run this piece of code, the output that i get is :

```
username:FT_SelfAdmin01 index: 2 value []
username:FT_SelfAdmin01 index: 4 value []
username:FT_SelfAdmin01 index: 6 value []
```

when i ran the above batch in echo on mode i get following

```
(
set username=!array[1]!  
 set /a nextindex=1+1  
 echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[nextindex]!] 
)
```

when i change  this line

`echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[%nextindex%]!]`

to this line
`echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[!nextindex!]!]`

i get this (as echo of code)

`echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[!nextindex!]!]`

and output changes to (i am giving only one line here)

`username:FT_SelfAdmin01 index: 4 value [nextindex]`

i am not able to understand what is happening ?

Comment: How do you initialize the array? What are the expected values?

Comment: i am initializing it with a loop , and the values are being populated properly , that i have checked. 
the expected values are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original line

```
echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[%nextindex%]!]
```

This will not work as the `%nextindex%` variable reference, not using delayed expansion, was replaced when the full `for %%a` block was parsed.

Changed line, now with delayed expansion

```
echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[!nextindex!]!]
              ^........^        ^.........^        ^......^         ^.^
```

The variables the parser sees are not what you think. It is not possible to use delayed expansion inside delayed expansion.

How to solve? `for` replaceable parameters

```
for %%b in (!nextindex!) do (
    echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!array[%%b]!]
)
```

Comment: this is just what i was searching for. !!! thanx , also i have edited my question for the typo u mentioned in first line , u please change ur answer accordingly so that future readers do not get confused :) thanx !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right (and that's kinda hard to say), something like this should help you:

@echo off

```
rem Just init the array
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C D E F) do (
  set array[!n!]=%%a
  set /A n+=1
)

for /L %%c  in (0,2,5) do (
   set username=!array[%%c]!
   set /a nextindex=%%c+1
   call set val=%%array[!nextindex!]%%
   echo username:!username! index: !nextindex! value [!val!]
)
```

the output of this is:

```
username:A index: 1 value [B]
username:C index: 3 value [D]
username:E index: 5 value [F]
```

Comment: i think u misunderstood my question completely , please have a look at the MC ND's answer, then i think your understanding will improve. thanx :)